Knowing if a custom widget is in Preview mode in Qt Designer
I am making custom widgets (plugins) for the Qt Designer, my problem is that I would
like to have them inactive when put into a layout, and "active" when in Preview mode.
What I mean by "active" or "inactive" in my case, is that my widgets need connections
to a database and I would not want to do this when designing the layout, however when
in Preview mode I would like to make it real and establish the connection.
I could not find the documentation about Preview mode.
Is there something I can use ?

I wouldn't suggest making a widget do that in any case while used in Designer, but, in any case, the simplest solution would be to check for the widget's window() and its windowTitle(), which normally contains the suffix - [Preview] when in preview mode.

I just found out that there's a possible "hack" that may be more accurate. When Designer shows the preview, it creates a custom QWidget container for it, which has a _q_custom_style_disabled property set, meaning that you could check if that property is set (if it is, it's not None or isinstance(value, bool)). Unfortunately this has two drawbacks: 1. the property is set after the widgets are created; 2. it's undocumented and may be changed/removed in future versions. In any case, you may check it in a showEvent() override (maybe along with an internal QTimer in the __init__).

To avoid doing unnecessary checks outside of the Designer context, you may set a class or instance attribute for the custom widget only when used within the plugin (for instance, in createWidget() or even while importing the class. For reference, see this related post: Can I style the top-level form in Designer preview?, and check the source for qttools/src/designer/src/lib/shared/previewmanager.cpp and qttools/src/designer/src/lib/shared/widgetfactory.cpp
